# Load an external JS file from a JS class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use an external js file on my site, it currently sits at the bottom of my boilerplate.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

I only need to load this script on specific pages or when a specific modal loads.

Is there a way to call the script from my javascript code. For example:

```
$(document).one('opened.fndtn.reveal', '#my-modal[data-reveal]', function () {
    //load places api
});
```

Also Google suggest having it on every page - why is this? I do not need to use it on every page.

Comment: [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)**

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

```
$.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places", function(){
  alert("script loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you don't have jQuery.

```
function inyectScript(url, success){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.id = "myScript";
        var done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState === 'loaded' || this.readyState === 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                success();
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```